# FuelPHP Oil produces empty migrations

Tags: php, migration, fuelphp

I am running PHP 5.4.6 and have installed FuelPHP 1.6. I am trying to generate a migration using

```
oil g migration posts title:varchar[50] --soft-delete
```

The migration produced looks like this

```
<?php
```

namespace Fuel\Migrations;

```
class Posts
{
    public function up()
    {

    }

    public function down()
    {

    }
}
```

Any suggesting what is causing this strange behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bug, but instead generate a migration file, do a model file.

```
oil g model posts title:var[50]
```

The Oil generator will create a migration file inside of

```
fuell/app/migrations/
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that the migration command is missing, so the generator doesn't know what to do with it. It should give an error, but appearently it doesn't.

Assuming this is meant to generate a migration that creates a table, the command should be:

```
oil g model create_posts title:var[50]
```